# Angular & Bootstrap Modal

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap

I have a data table, with a button that opens a Modal (Bootstrap Modal) for each table row.

I would like that when I open a one row modal, I get the data from that row.

it works with `"console.log (this.array[index])"`. And also when I open the Modal, it always shows me the data of the first row of the table.

I think I'm missing an index parameter in the modal.

Thank you in advance for your help.

My TS File :

```
    export class ListeDevisComponent implements OnInit {
  listeDevis = [];

  constructor(private listeDevisService: ListeDevisService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.listeDevisService.getListeDevis().subscribe(
      (data: any) => {
        this.listeDevis = data;
      },
      (error) => {
        console.error(error);
      },
      () => {
        console.log("Liste Devis Success");
      }
    );
  }

  voirIndexDevis(index) {
    console.log(this.listeDevis[index]);
  }
}
```

My HTML File :

```
    <table class="table">
  <thead class="thead-dark">
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">ID Devis</th>
      <th scope="col">Date Devis</th>
      <th scope="col">Actions</th>
      <th scope="col">Nom Complet</th>
      <th scope="col">Contact</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let liste of listeDevis; let i = index">
      <td>{{ liste.idDevis }}</td>
      <td>{{ liste.dateDevis }}</td>
      <td>
        <button
          class="btn btn-primary"
          data-toggle="modal"
          data-target="#exampleModal"
          (click)="voirIndexDevis(i)"
        >
          Test Modal Actions
        </button>
      </td>
      <td>{{ liste.nom }} {{ liste.prenom }}</td>
      <td>{{ liste.email }}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<!-- Modal -->
<div
  class="modal fade"
  id="exampleModal"
  tabindex="-1"
  aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel"
  aria-hidden="true"
>
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Liste Devis</h5>
        <button
          type="button"
          class="close"
          data-dismiss="modal"
          aria-label="Close"
        >
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="row" *ngFor="let liste of listeDevis; let i = index">
          <div class="col-lg-3 col-12 border">
            <h5>Type Installation :</h5>
            {{ liste.typeInstallation }}
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-3 col-12 border">
            <h5>Quantité :</h5>
            {{ liste.qte }}
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-3 col-12 border">
            <h5>Charge Nominale :</h5>
            {{ liste.charge }}
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-3 col-12 border">
            <h5>Nombres Arrêts :</h5>
            {{ liste.arrets }}
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-3 col-12 border">
            <h5>Type Gaine :</h5>
            {{ liste.typeGaine }}
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-3 col-12 border">
            <h5>Local Machinerie :</h5>
            {{ liste.localMachinerie }}
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-3 col-12 border">
            <h5>Mode Entrainement :</h5>
            {{ liste.modeEntrainement }}
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-3 col-12 border">
            <h5>Modèle :</h5>
            {{ liste.modeles }}
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-3 col-12 border">
            <h5>Couleur :</h5>
            {{ liste.couleur }}
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-3 col-12 border">
            <h5>Dimension Cabine :</h5>
            {{ liste.dimensionCabine }}
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-3 col-12 border">
            <h5>Plafond :</h5>
            {{ liste.plafond }}
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-3 col-12 border">
            <h5>Mirroir :</h5>
            {{ liste.mirroir }}
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-3 col-12 border">
            <h5>Porte Cabine :</h5>
            {{ liste.porteCabine }}
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-3 col-12 border">
            <h5>Accessoires :</h5>
            {{ liste.accessoires }}
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-3 col-12 border">
            <h5>Type Porte Paliers :</h5>
            {{ liste.typePortePaliers }}
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-3 col-12 border">
            <h5>Ouverture :</h5>
            {{ liste.ouverture }}
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-3 col-12 border">
            <h5>Passage Libre :</h5>
            {{ liste.passageLibre }}
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-3 col-12 border">
            <h5>Finition :</h5>
            {{ liste.finition }}
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-3 col-12 border">
            <h5>Votre Nom :</h5>
            {{ liste.nom }}
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-3 col-12 border">
            <h5>Votre Prenom :</h5>
            {{ liste.prenom }}
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-3 col-12 border">
            <h5>Destinataire :</h5>
            {{ liste.destinataire }}
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-3 col-12 border">
            <h5>Votre E-mail :</h5>
            {{ liste.email }}
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-3 col-12 border">
            <h5>Votre Numéro Tel :</h5>
            {{ liste.telephone }}
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-3 col-12 border">
            <h5>Votre Disponibilité :</h5>
            {{ liste.disponibilite }}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">
          Fermer
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: how you pass the data into the model? Currently you iterate over the `listeDevis` in both table and modal!

Comment: @ramzanali In the table, I get all the rows. And in the modal, I get always the first row of the table... I would like that when I open a one row modal, I get the data from that row and not always the first row of the table :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the row data, pass `liste` instead of `i`:

```
(click)="voirIndexDevis(liste)"
```

Then, set the current list item in the component file:

```
export class ListeDevisComponent implements OnInit {
  listeDevis = [];
  currentListe;

  constructor(private listeDevisService: ListeDevisService) {}

  // ngOnInit removed for brevity

  voirIndexDevis(liste) {
    this.currentListe = liste;
  }
}
```

Then adjust the modal, removing the `*ngFor` and adding the safe navigation operator to each instance of `currentListe.prop`:

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div
  class="modal fade"
  id="exampleModal"
  tabindex="-1"
  aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel"
  aria-hidden="true"
>
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Liste Devis</h5>
        <button
          type="button"
          class="close"
          data-dismiss="modal"
          aria-label="Close"
        >
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-3 col-12 border">
            <h5>Type Installation :</h5>
            {{ currentListe?.typeInstallation }}
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-3 col-12 border">
            <h5>Quantité :</h5>
            {{ currentListe?.qte }}
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-3 col-12 border">
            <h5>Charge Nominale :</h5>
            {{ currentListe?.charge }}
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-3 col-12 border">
            <h5>Nombres Arrêts :</h5>
            {{ currentListe?.arrets }}
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-3 col-12 border">
            <h5>Type Gaine :</h5>
            {{ currentListe?.typeGaine }}
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-3 col-12 border">
            <h5>Local Machinerie :</h5>
            {{ currentListe?.localMachinerie }}
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-3 col-12 border">
            <h5>Mode Entrainement :</h5>
            {{ currentListe?.modeEntrainement }}
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-3 col-12 border">
            <h5>Modèle :</h5>
            {{ currentListe?.modeles }}
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-3 col-12 border">
            <h5>Couleur :</h5>
            {{ currentListe?.couleur }}
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-3 col-12 border">
            <h5>Dimension Cabine :</h5>
            {{ currentListe?.dimensionCabine }}
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-3 col-12 border">
            <h5>Plafond :</h5>
            {{ currentListe?.plafond }}
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-3 col-12 border">
            <h5>Mirroir :</h5>
            {{ currentListe?.mirroir }}
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-3 col-12 border">
            <h5>Porte Cabine :</h5>
            {{ currentListe?.porteCabine }}
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-3 col-12 border">
            <h5>Accessoires :</h5>
            {{ currentListe?.accessoires }}
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-3 col-12 border">
            <h5>Type Porte Paliers :</h5>
            {{ currentListe?.typePortePaliers }}
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-3 col-12 border">
            <h5>Ouverture :</h5>
            {{ currentListe?.ouverture }}
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-3 col-12 border">
            <h5>Passage Libre :</h5>
            {{ currentListe?.passageLibre }}
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-3 col-12 border">
            <h5>Finition :</h5>
            {{ currentListe?.finition }}
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-3 col-12 border">
            <h5>Votre Nom :</h5>
            {{ currentListe?.nom }}
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-3 col-12 border">
            <h5>Votre Prenom :</h5>
            {{ currentListe?.prenom }}
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-3 col-12 border">
            <h5>Destinataire :</h5>
            {{ currentListe?.destinataire }}
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-3 col-12 border">
            <h5>Votre E-mail :</h5>
            {{ currentListe?.email }}
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-3 col-12 border">
            <h5>Votre Numéro Tel :</h5>
            {{ currentListe?.telephone }}
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-3 col-12 border">
            <h5>Votre Disponibilité :</h5>
            {{ currentListe?.disponibilite }}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">
          Fermer
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If the safe navigation operator (`currentListe?.prop`) does not work, you could also use an ngIf:

```
<div class="row" *ngIf="currentListe">
<!-- row data -->
</div>
```

---

### Alternative Solution

Because we all love options, you can also control the modal manually. First, remove the logic that connects the row buttons to the modal:

```
<button
  class="btn btn-primary"
  (click)="voirIndexDevis(liste)"
>
  Test Modal Actions
</button>
```

Then add logic to the component file to show/hide the modal:

```
export class ListeDevisComponent implements OnInit {
  listeDevis = [];
  currentListe;
  showModal: boolean = false;

  constructor(private listeDevisService: ListeDevisService) {}

  // ngOnInit removed for brevity

  voirIndexDevis(liste) {
    this.currentListe = liste;
    this.showModal = true;
  }

  hideModal() {
    this.showModal = false;
  }
}
```

Then update the modal show/hide logic by adding an `*ngIf` to the outer `div` and updating the close button in the upper-right corner and the footer button to call `hideModal()` when clicked:

```
<div
  *ngIf="showModal"
  class="modal fade"
  id="exampleModal"
  tabindex="-1"
  aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel"
  aria-hidden="true"
>
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Liste Devis</h5>
        <button
          type="button"
          class="close"
          onclick="hideModal()"
          aria-label="Close"
        >
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <!-- hide modal body for brevity -->
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" onclick="hideModal()">
          Fermer
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you give please an example ? I dit the changes but I get now the last row data on Modal :p

Comment: Why the `*ngFor` in the modal template?

Comment: Because I was getting the error " Cannot read property 'typeInstallation' of undefined "

Comment: Ahhh, gotcha. I've updated with an example, including avoiding that error

Comment: I've also included another method of controlling the modal that allows you to more explicitly define when the modal is open (without jQuery)

Comment: Thank you so much ! It's working :D ... Your were right ! and @joaoFreitas solution too :) I needed to create a variable to contain the row data that I click :D

Thank you again for your time :)

Answer (score 0):

At the `voirIndexDevis` function you have to do the same event into the service file but this time only receive the `listeDevis` with the index you sent. But i advise you to create a new variable like `Devis` and paste the data from that event so that variable only contain the one that you click.

Comment: Thank you for your Help ... Can you give me an example how to do it ? :)